# cap deploy in rails - gem require error for mongo

Tags: ruby, mongodb, capistrano, bundler

I'm trying to deploy to a ruby app to a test server environment using capistrano but am getting a GemRequireError with mongo.

Here is the error i'm getting when i run `cap test deploy`:

`rake aborted!
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem 'mongo'.
Gem Load Error is: uninitialized constant BSON::Document`

Have done a bundle on my local env and committed my Gemfile and Gemfile.lock to my repo.
Any pointers would be great as i have tried everything I can think of as a newbie!

Thanks : )

Comment: Are you executing within the bundler environment? What happens if you run `bundle exec cap test deploy`?

Comment: Same error happens whenever i run `bundle exec cap test deploy`

Comment: Do you also get the same error if you `bundle exec irb` and then `require 'mongo'`?

Comment: I get 'true' whenever I run `bundle exec irb`